# Connecting Dash (Plotly) to API with html.Script

Tags: plotly-dash

Looking to connect an app built in dash to a third-party API.

The html that connects is something like this...

```
<script src="https://api.website.com/static/api.js" data-app-id="1234" >
</script >
```

Dash has a script component called **html.Script** that replaces the script tag in raw html. You can read more about it here: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/script

The issue is that the raw html api code contains the unique attribute **data-app-id**, and Dash's html.Script component doesn't seem to support a keyword argument that would allow one to place **data-app-id="1234"** in the component.

Any thoughts how to put data-app-id="1234" in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this via setting the `external_scripts` property of `Dash`:

```
external_scripts = [
    {
        "src": "https://api.website.com/static/api.js",
        "data-app-id": "1234",
    },
]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_scripts=external_scripts)
```

Look at the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) for more info.

---

To verify it is working: Run your app and in the browser view page source and you will see it shows:

```
<script src="https://api.website.com/static/api.js" data-app-id="1234"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to connect to https://api.memberstack.io/static/memberstack.js, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe add the protocol to the src (i.e. https)

Comment: ah, that memberstack.js file is local. it's not related to your code. so the external script isn't actually appearing in the source when the dash code is executed.

Comment: yes, sorry, the script is actually written with the full https URL. Stack overflow is converting the URL to a link in these comments.

Comment: This (with the protocol) seems to work `external_scripts = [
    {
        "src": "https://api.memberstack.io/static/memberstack.js",
        "data-memberstack-id": "1234",
    }
]`

Comment: you are seeing the the code in your source when you run the dash app? I still am not. If so, are you running the code locally or remotely?

Comment: Yes. I'm running it locally

Comment: Interesting. What does the source code in your browser return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232553/discussion-between-bas-van-der-linden-and-dlh).

Comment: It worked after I set changed stylesheet to script :)